# Tengo un problema con una validación personalizada en un formulario reactivo de angular

Tags: javascript, angular, formularios, validación

Estoy practicando las validaciones personalizadas , por ende creé una la cual tiene el objetivo de marcar como invalido el campo si el usuario coloca en el campo de apellido la palabra 'molestar'

[EL PROBLEMA] : cada vez que quiero utilizar esta validacion me marca el campo como invalido sin importar si el formulario es valido o no. Simplemente la implemento y me lo marca como invalido.

La validación customizada fue creada en un servicio y es la siguiente:

```
noapellido(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (control.value?.toLowerCase() === 'molestar') {
        return {
            noapellido: true
        };
    }else{
        return { noapellido: null };
    }
}
```

- implemento el servicio:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private validator: ValidpersonalizadasService) { };
```

- implemento la validación customizada:

```
this.forma = this.fb.group({
    nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
    apellido: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),               this.validator.noapellido]],
    correo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')]]
});
```

Sin importar lo coloque en el campo , me marca el formulario como invalido y quisiera resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la validación es correcta, debes retornar un `null`, si no lo es, retornas un objeto y este debe contener la estructura que requieras para saber que fallo.

Tu código debería quedar algo así:

```
    noapellido(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (control.value?.toLowerCase() === 'molestar') {
      return {
        noapellido: true
      };
    }else{
      //Si la validación es correcta retornas null
      return
    }
```

Editando...

Comment: tienes razón estuve un largo tiempo buscando el error y ese era : yo estaba retornando un objeto en lugar  de retornar un 'null' que es lo que se debe retornar cuando no hay error en el campo. No se que clase de sintaxis estaba queriendo implementar. Te agradezco mucho por tu tiempo.